# Вопрос о постановке запятой в простом предложении

Tags: запятые

В этом предложении нужна запятая в скобках? Если да, то в связи с каким правилом?

**Пожалуйста, введите сообщение(,) размером не более чем 35000 символов.**

Comment: Не нужна, согласен с отвечающими.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. В заданном предложении нет обособления. Несогласованное определение используется в качестве **основной** информации:

*Пожалуйста, введите сообщение **размером не более чем 35000 символов.***

2. Но в другом тексте это же определение может быть уточняющим, что видно по содержанию. Тогда несогласованное определение обособляется в качестве **уточнения**:

*Вы также можете ввести сообщение, **размером не более чем 35000 символов.***

**ПРАВИЛО**

**[Розенталь, пункт 1](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=110#pp110)**

Обычно обособляются несогласованные определения, дополняющие или уточняющие представление о лице либо **предмете,** который сам по себе (без определения) достаточно конкретен, уже **известен**.

Answer (score 2):

Конечно нет! Ну зачем она тут может быть нужна?! Сообщение (какое?) размером...